# Content type error when using rust actix download file

Tags: rust, actix-web

I want to download a zip file using rust acitx_web, this is the server side code look like:

```
pub async fn download_project(
    form: web::Json<DownloadProj>
) -> Result<NamedFile> {
    let trash_result = handle_compress_proj(&form.0);
    return Ok(trash_result.unwrap());
}
```

`handle_compress_proj` compress the folder to a zip file and return the zip file to the client side, this is the handle_compress_proj look like:

```
pub fn handle_compress_proj(_req: &DownloadProj) -> Option<NamedFile> {
    let archive_path = gen_zip();
    let file_result = NamedFile::open(archive_path);
    if let Err(err) = file_result {
        error!("read file error,{}", err);
        return None;
    }
    return Some(file_result.unwrap());
}
```

when I invoke this api, the server side told the error `Content type error`. what should I do to fixed this issue? This is all the actix dependencies:

```
actix-web = "4"
actix-web-validator = "5.0.1"
actix-rt = "2.9.0"
actix-multipart = "0.6.1"
actix-files = "0.6.2"
```

I have tried to tweak the code like this:

```
pub async fn download_project(
    req: HttpRequest,
    form: web::Json<DownloadProj>
) -> impl Responder {
    let path = handle_compress_proj(&form.0);
    match NamedFile::open(&path) {
        Ok(fe) => NamedFile::into_response(fe, &req),
        Err(_) => HttpResponse::BadRequest().json("can't download file")
    }
}
```

still could not fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

return type should be `actix_web::Result<impl actix_web::Responder>` and actix will add proper header depends on what file type you are returning.

e.i.

```
#[actix_web::get("/test-zip")]
async fn test_zip() -> actix_web::Result<impl actix_web::Responder> {

    let path = std::path::PathBuf::from("ZIP_PATH");
    
    if path.exists() {
        let file = actix_files::NamedFile::open(path)?; 
        Ok( file.use_last_modified(true) ) 
    } else {
        Err(actix_web::error::ErrorBadRequest("File not Found") )
    }
}
```